# C++11 shared_ptr released multiple times under multithreading

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Under g++ 4.8.5 compiling, it is found that improper use of sharedptr will cause multiple destruction of shared_ptr.

Fake code：

```
#include<memory>

class Demo
{
public:
    ~Demo()
    {
        // Do something and cost some milliseconds
    }    
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<Demo> DemoPtr;

DemoPtr global_demo;
DemoPtr instance() {return global_demo;}

// Main thread
int main()
{
    global_demo = std::make_shared<Demo>();
    // Do something
}

// Thread A
void thread_func()
{
    // Do something
    
    if(instance() != nullptr)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    // Do something
}
```

When the main thread ends, the global_demo reference count is reduced to 0, and global_demo begins to be destructed. When global_demo is being destructed, thread A calls instance() and makes a judgment, which causes the reference count of global_demo to increase by one again, and then when the local variable is released, the reference count is reduced to 0 again, resulting in the destruction of the object pointed to by global_demo The function is called again.

View gcc source code：

```
//*************__shared_count***************//
__shared_count&
operator=(const __shared_count& __r) noexcept
{
    _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>* __tmp = __r._M_pi;
    if (__tmp != _M_pi)
    {
        if (__tmp != 0)
            __tmp->_M_add_ref_copy();
        if (_M_pi != 0)
            _M_pi->_M_release();
        _M_pi = __tmp;
    }
    return *this;
}

//************_Sp_counted_base*****************//
void
_M_add_ref_copy()
{ __gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(&_M_use_count, 1); }
```

So, this is a GCC bug?

Should I use std::weak_ptr to solve this problem in this case?
So, my instance() method code like this?

```
DemoPtr instance() 
{
    std::weak_ptr<Demo> w(global_demo);
    if(!w.expired())
    {
        return w.lock();
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: You should probably have your main function wait until all the other threads finish.

Comment: I think you oversimplified your code. There is nothing in your code that destructs the `global_demo`. Assuming that there is a `global_demo = nullptr;` somewhere, then what you have is UB. The copy constructor is const, but the destructor is non-const. It is illegal to have a const and non-const method running simultaneously.

Comment: Upon closer reading, I think you are referring to the destruction of `global_demo` that is a consequence of the destruction of global variables during process termination. In which case you already have UB even without the race condition, because your detached thread is accessing `global_demo` potentially after it has destructed.

Comment: One of my questions is, in the source code of the shared_ptr assignment construction of GCC, for the object pointer that is being destroyed, when the useCount is 0, why does the assignment construction of the pointer go directly to usecount +1 instead of UseCount is 0 to check. If the assignment is constructed successfully, this behavior will result in undefined behavior. By the way, there are many concurrent threads in my actual application. I'm not sure when some threads end, so I can't join and wait for all threads to end before ending the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

> So, this is a GCC bug?

No. It is a bug in the program:

> global_demo is being destructed
>
> thread A calls instance()
>
> ```
> DemoPtr instance() {return global_demo;}
> ```

You are making a copy (`return global_demo;`) of an object whose lifetime has ended (is being destructed). The behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

> Should I use std::weak_ptr to solve this problem in this case?

This would not fix the bug. What you must do is join any threads that depend on static variables before returning from `main`. <sub>It may technically be OK to join a thread after `main` has returned, within a destructor of a static object as long as that object is guaranteed to be destroyed before the depended static object. But good luck with that.</sub>

---

> for some threads I cannot control the end.

Then you must avoid using any static variables in those threads. In the example case, create a thread local copy of `global_demo`, and use that within the thread instead.

Comment: One of my questions is, in the source code of the shared_ptr assignment construction of GCC, for the object pointer that is being destroyed, when the useCount is 0, why does the assignment construction of the pointer go directly to usecount +1 instead of UseCount is 0 to check. If the assignment is constructed successfully, this behavior will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: In my actual application, there are many concurrent threads, and for some threads I cannot control the end. I have some operations in the destruction of the object, so this will lead to an object being destructed when the object is obtained in other threads, so undefined behavior will occur, the phenomenon I see here That is, two threads are destructing the object at the same time. How should I deal with this scenario, please give me more guidance, thank you

Comment: @zhaojs `why does the assignment construction of the pointer` Behaviour of the program is undefined, so anything could happen. Something happened. and UB is the reason why it happened. `for some threads I cannot control the end` See edited answer.